# Decorating an IObservable through a Subject - preferred approach?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have been creating a series of IObservable extension methods, which are domain-specific but basically all have the form of passing the existing sequence through another class (which implements ISubject), and providing the net output.

After I'd done a few of these, I twigged that there was a pattern, and managed to distill what I was doing right down to the following:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an observable sequence that is the output of subscribing the existing sequence to
    /// a subject (the result of <paramref name="subjectFactory"/>) and consuming the result
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Kinda suspicious that this doesn't exist out of the box, now I've pared
    /// it right down to what it basically is</returns>
    public static IObservable<T> Decorate<T>(this IObservable<T> input, Func<ISubject<T>> subjectFactory)
    {
        return Observable.Create<T>(observer =>
            {
                var processor = subjectFactory();
                var subscriptions = new[]
                    {
                        processor.Subscribe(observer),
                        input.Subscribe(processor),
                    };
                return new CompositeDisposable(subscriptions);
            });
    }
```

Putting it like this reduced all the other extension methods to one-liners. But this is *so* generic that I was quite suspicious that this didn't exist already. But I couldn't find one.

So the question is: does this functionality exist in the base RX libraries anywhere? I'm looking for one that takes an `ISubject<T>`, handles all the subscription ceremony and spits out the result (like the above)

--

Edit: yes, comments regarding avoiding Subject implementations and leaning on Create are well made. In this case I didn't want to expose the operations as methods for a couple of reasons:

- they make for some fairly impenetrable code in the Create lambdas
- there's an engine that needs to stitch them all together into a pipeline, and this way it can do so polymorphically (ie without knowing what the operations are). In retrospect though, it could achieve the same thing if it received a set of operators as delegates (ie `IEnumerable<Func<IObservable<T>,IObservable<T>>>` and effectively created the subscriber chain that way - ie pass the input observable through each func in turn to get the output)

The operations themselves lean on an internal `Subject<T>` to do all the heavy lifting, so it's not like they're implementing `ISubject<T>` *from scratch*, which I know is the road to hell...

Comment: The red flag is that you have a class implementing `ISubject`. You can probably just define operators with `Create` instead. If you really need a *hot* transformation, then try this overload of [Publish](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229147(v=vs.103).aspx) instead.

Comment: Could you provide an example of one of these being used?

Comment: Sure, if you provide an example of what one of your subject classes are doing I'll see if I can convert it to `Create`.

Comment: And if you really need a subject, then you should consider composition rather than inheritance. See also [To Use Subject or Not To Use Subject](http://davesexton.com/blog/post/To-Use-Subject-Or-Not-To-Use-Subject.aspx).

Comment: All good things @DaveSexton said...

Answer (score 1):

Yes I think your function is just a variation of [Multicast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229708(v=vs.103).aspx):

```
public static IObservable<T> Decorate<T>(this IObservable<T> input, Func<ISubject<T>> subjectFactory)
{
    return input.Multicast(subjectFactory, t => t);
}
```

But to be honest, I agree with Dave's comments.  Chances are you don't really need multicast functionality.  The common pattern I find is that the domain specific classes should not be `ISubject` implementations, but should just have methods that take an `IObservable` as input and return a new `IObservable` as output (with their domain logic applied).  Something like:

```
IObservable<Bar> DoLogic(IObservable<Foo> foos)
{
    return foos.Select(foo => ...);
}
```